# Reading Json object in MATLAB

Tags: json, matlab

```
{
  "NX-Matlab":
 {
    "Volumen": 200,
    "Wanddicke": 3
  },

  "Matlab-NX": {

    "n1": {
      "Fließ barriere oder Fließhilfe": 1,
      " Querschnittsart": 1,
      "Geometrieparameter": {
        "Breite": 2,
        "Höhe": 4.479,
        "Anzahl": 3
```

Code:

```
clc


fid = fopen('filename.json', 'r');

str = fread(fid,'*char').';

fclose(fid);

J = jsondecode(str);

J.Matlab_NX.n1.Geometrieparameter.Breite = 3;

outputjson = jsonencode(J);

fileID = fopen('filename.json','w');
fwrite(fileID, outputjson);
fclose(fileID);
```

I wanted to replace Updated parameter (Breite) in file. Need guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using R2016b or later, you can use [`jsondecode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsondecode.html) to convert your JSON data into a `struct`. You can then modify the fields you want, change the value, and re-encode as json using [`jsonencode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html).

If your data is in a file, you can read the contents of the file in as a string prior to decoding with `jsondecode`

```
fid = fopen('filename.json', 'r');
str = fread(fid, '*char').';
fclose(fid);
J = jsondecode(str);

% Change the value
J.Matlab_NX.n1.Geometrieparameter.Breite = 3
```

If you are using older versions of MATLAB, the [JSONlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab--a-toolbox-to-encode-decode-json-files) File Exchange submission is very excellent and will also transform your data into a `struct`.

It's worth noting that with either of these methods, the fieldnames will have to be converted to [valid fieldnames](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html#btcg64n) so spaces, hypens, etc. may not be preserved as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2014b you can also use the internal functions `matlab.internal.webservices.fromJSON()` and `matlab.internal.webservices.toJSON()` to convert a JSON string to Matlab data structures and back to JSON.

Your example would then read:

```
obj = matlab.internal.webservices.fromJSON( fileread( 'filename.json'));
obj.Matlab_NX.n1.Geometrieparameter.Breite = 3;
jsonStr = matlab.internal.webservices.toJSON( obj);
% write jsonStr to file if needed
```

Answer (score 0):

Just flagging that the most efficient way to read and parse a JSON file is through a combination of `jsondecode` and [`fileread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html).

Instead of opening and closing the file "manually", just rely on `fileread`, which will load its contents in memory as a character vector.

```matlab
contents = jsondecode(fileread(file_path))
```